# Network question regarding data and wifi

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection, data

I wanted to ask whether on Android phones it is normal to access another phone who only uses data and no wifi from a phone that only uses wifi and no data, using an app such as WhatsApp to place a call.

I am trying to debug in a phone setting where one or both phones may have network problems, and was thinking about whether anyone can help me with this.

Both phones are running Android 12 and 11.

Thanks.

Comment: What network problems exactly? Indeed what you mention is normal and unrelated to any specific software, it's just using WiFi tethering in one phone and connecting to an AP given by another which happens to have only mobile data, a very common setup. What exactly are the problem you've been experiencing?

Comment: Access how? Your question doesn't actually specify tethering, it specifies two internet connected devices, one via wifi and one via cellular.